# How to use function reference for Java 8?

Tags: java, function, lambda, reference

How to use function reference in this case (function reference instead x.length())?

```
private static Function<String, Integer> f1 = x -> x.length();
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this

```
private static Function<String, Integer> f1 = String::length;
```